# How to call parent function in jquery apline js

Tags: alpine.js

I'm facing one issue when clicking on the button this.reloadDatatable() is not called. how can I call reloadDatatable() function from toggle function? below is the demo code for that. Thank you.

```
<button type="button" @click="addSettingContainer.toggle();"></button>

Alpine.data('initOrderGrid', () => ({
    addSettingContainer: {
        toggle() {
            this.reloadDatatable();
        }
    },
    reloadDatatable: function() {
        console.log('a');
    },
}));
```

Comment: Can you please help me to figure out this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access the parent object's scope from a child object without some ugly hacks. However it seem that you want to use an event system: on a button click you want to reload the data table. Alpine.js has builtin event system, we can use the [`$dispatch`](https://alpinejs.dev/magics/dispatch) function to emit a custom event and the [`x-on`](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/on) method to capture our custom event:

```
<div x-data="initOrderGrid"
     @reload-data-table.window="reloadDatatable">
</div>

<div x-data>
  <button @click="$dispatch('reload-data-table')">Reload data table</button>
</div>


<script>
document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
  Alpine.data('initOrderGrid', () => ({
    reloadDatatable() {
      console.log('Data table reloaded');
    }
  }))
})
</script>
```