# Can I update x-data from a child component that has it's own x-data?

Tags: alpine.js

So I have code similar to this

```
<div x-data="dataManager()">
    <some-other-component />
    <div x-text="id"></div>
</div>
<script>
    dataManager() {
        return {
            id: null,
            someOtherId: null,
            helperFunction(val){ this.id = val}
        }
    }
</script>
```

```
<div x-data"{data1: "1", data2: "2"}">
    <input @change="helperfunction(val)">
</div>
```

So I have the helper function being called when the input is changed, but it doesn't seem to be updating the parent x-data id, as the id div doesn't change. I'm pretty new to Alpine, so not sure if I'm doing anything silly here. Any help would be much appreciated

I'm using Alpine 3.10.0 if that changes anything

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call parent function in jquery apline js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72377989/how-to-call-parent-function-in-jquery-apline-js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using Alpine 3, you should be using [Alpine.data](https://alpinejs.dev/globals/alpine-data). Alpine 3 supports scoped `x-data`. Below is a code example that works as expected.

```html
<div x-data="dataManager()">
    <div x-data"{data1: "1", data2: "2"}">
        <input x-on:change="helperFunction($event.target.value)">
    </div>
    <div x-text="id"></div>
</div>

<script>
    document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
        Alpine.data('dataManager', () => ({
            id: null,
            someOtherId: null,
            helperFunction(val){ this.id = val}
        }))
    })
</script>
```

A few notes:

- You misspelled `helperfunction` (lowercase f)
- `val` doesn't exist in your example
- You'll have to check yourself if this works using your component but I would be surprised if it didn't